# Enable MariaDB Error Logging into file without service restart / without downtime?

Tags: mariadb, error-logging, error-log, mariadb-10.4

Is it possible to enable / configure the mariaDB error logging at runtime and make changes affect without a service restart / downtime?

I'm using `mariadDB 10.4.28` and the error logging into a log file is not configured at the moment. I know how i can enable it, but i read that a service restart is neccessary to apply the changes in the `my.cnf`.

Is there actually a way or not? Does it make a difference in confiuration if i run mariadb as a replication / in replication mode?